# getting all repos in a Github api query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, github, repository

I have the following query hooked up to a rails app.  It only seems to be returning 30 projects at a time, even with an increased per_page count.  However, if I make the same request via the browser, I get the expected number of projects.

`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=license:gpl+license:lgpl+license:gpl+license:mit+forks:0+stars:1..2000+pushed:%3E2019-12-11+language:ruby+language:javascript&per_page=100`

controller:

```
def request_projects
    api_key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:github)
    query = "#{Project::LICENSES}+#{Project::FORKS}+#{Project::STARS}+#{Project::DATE}+#{Project::LANGUAGES}"
    uri = URI.parse("#{Project::GITHUB_BASE_URL}?q=#{query}&client_secret=#{api_key[:secret]}&per_page=100")
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    Project.create_from_request(res.body)
  end
```

Model:

```
def self.create_from_request(request_body)
    data = JSON.parse(request_body, symbolize_names: true)
    data[:items].each do |item|
      name = item[:name]
      owner = item[:owner][:login]
      url = item[:html_url]
      stars = item[:stargazers_count]

      Project.create(name: name, owner: owner, url: url, stars: stars) if !Project.exists?(name: name, owner: owner)
    end
  end
```

Comment: There is no mention anywhere in [the docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#constructing-a-search-query) of per_page.

Comment: Can you please attach the res.body in a gist file and add link of link. I have tried from browser, curl and rails console all are returning 100 results with the url mentioned in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AzmatRana, here's the gist.  

https://gist.github.com/mkrul/9e58c049ca7611bdf77b8a664f301af8

Comment: Okay.... I just counted the results, and it's 100.  But for some reason only a small handfull of projects are being created.  Like 20 or 30.  So my problem isnt with the api call itself, it's with `Project.create`

Comment: @MishaKrul one reason could be because of the `if !Project.exists?(name: name, owner: owner)`  check before creating the project. I have seen the gist and for that gist it is creating 100 records for me. 
`query = "#{Project::LICENSES}+#{Project::FORKS}+#{Project::STARS}+#{Project::DATE}+#{Project::LANGUAGES}"
    uri = URI.parse("#{Project::GITHUB_BASE_URL}?q=#{query")`

I think its output is different then the gist you provided because in these loc's you have used the dynamic links, github urls, ids etc. 
Test your `create_from_request` loop it should run 100 times.

Comment: @MishaKrul any updates ?

Comment: @AzmatRana yes, I was able to get it working.  It was a pagination issue.